# Installing Ubuntu through USB on a Mac

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, boot, macbook

My Superdrive is broken and I can't burn dvds. So, in order to install Ubuntu 11.04 on my Macbook Pro 5.5 I thought of booting from a USB disk and install it that way. I have tried using dd and UNetbootin but neither seemed to make the USB disk bootable. I have rEFIt installed and when the computer boots up, I get to choose from OSX, Windows 7 (I have a partion for that) and the USB disk with Tux as an icon. Once I select the USB disk is just starts Windows.

I even tried pressing F8 when it seems to load Windows and I get the Windows Boot menu, the thing is, it only shows Windows 7 as a boot option.

Is there any way I can boot up from the USB?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your first boot device as USB drive in BIOS settings? You can use LiLi to create bootable usb drive. If you want more application to try you can use this [link](http://www.toptrix.net/2012/03/bootable-usb-making-tools-windows-linux.html)

Comment: What BIOS settings? It's a Macintosh...